# Bootstrap 4 Cards and Navs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put my card next to my navigation that is vertical, but it decides that it needs to go under. So how can I fix this solution? I've been spending hours on trying to fix this problem

Work:

```html
<?php include 'includes/db.php'?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Admin Panel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
  
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#new-items" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New</a>
     <ul class="collapse" id="new-items">
      <li class="nav-link"><a class="" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> New Post</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a class="" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> New Category</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Posts</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Categories</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comments</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
  <div style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-block">
       <div class="col-xs-3 float-left"><i class="fa fa-signal" style="font-size:5em"></i></div>
       <div class="col-xs-9 float-right">
        <div style="font-size:2.5em">20</div>
        <div style="">Posts</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="card-footer">
       <div class="float-left">View Posts</div>
       <div class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-block">
       <div class="col-xs-3 float-left"><i class="fa fa-signal" style="font-size:5em"></i></div>
       <div class="col-xs-9 float-right">
        <div style="font-size:2.5em">20</div>
        <div style="">Posts</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="card-footer">
       <div class="float-left">View Posts</div>
       <div class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   
  <footer></footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

*If anyone can figure this out, it will be greatly appreciated* Please also note that this is an administrator panel for a blog I am making (Custom CMS) so if you have any ideas on that as well, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't look like a situation where you should use a card. Have you considered using badges instead: `<a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="badge badge-light">20</span></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could acheive this by Using css floating styles. I add a custom classes for both navigation and cards div and apply float:left property for both divs. Break(br) tag is removed. Immediate first child of card is empty, hence I made it to invisible.

Another method you can use float-left css classes for acheiving float:left css properties in both divs.

Please find the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
    <style>
.Cls_navigation,.Cls_card{float:left}

.Cls_card > div:first-child{display:none;}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>

    <div class="col-lg-2 Cls_navigation">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#new-items" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New</a>
                <ul class="collapse" id="new-items">
                    <li class="nav-link"><a class="" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> New Post</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a class="" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> New Category</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Posts</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Categories</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comments</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-8 Cls_card">
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 float-left"><i class="fa fa-signal" style="font-size:5em"></i></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 float-right">
                            <div style="font-size:2.5em">20</div>
                            <div style="">Posts</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="float-left">View Posts</div>
                        <div class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 float-left"><i class="fa fa-signal" style="font-size:5em"></i></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 float-right">
                            <div style="font-size:2.5em">20</div>
                            <div style="">Posts</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="float-left">View Posts</div>
                        <div class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You very much!! But how could I float the next box under my first?

Comment: <style>
.Cls_navigation,.Cls_card{float:left}

.Cls_card > div:first-child{display:none;}

</style> Please refer my code too

Comment: I meant my boxes being side by side since they are under one big column and Cls_card is being used for all of them. I need them side by side so I can continue with my project

Comment: could you please share a screenshot if any that will be helpful to me for providing the solution.